# Seleção do Menu Dropdown

Tags: css, dropdown

Gostaria que ao mostrar o menu `dropdown`, a `li` que o contém continuasse selecionada. Gostaria de saber se há como fazer isso só com CSS.

Segue o exemplo. Valeu!

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=show-hide-dropdown-on-mouse-hover

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No caso você quer que `Produtos` continue com o cinza mais escuro e a fonte branca, após abrir o menu dropdown? Tipo isso http://jsfiddle.net/hmredmond/meeqR/ ?

Answer (score 2):

Para que o `li` também fique com o background basta juntar `ul li:hover` no CSS. Podes também juntar `> a` se quiseres a côr branca no texto. `> a` significa os elementos `a` que são descendentes diretos de `li`, portanto só afetando o primeiro `a`  e não os outros que estão em níveis mais profundos.

Dessa maneira todos os `li` descendentes de `ul` que tenham o mouse dentro desse elemento recebem essa regra. E repara que como os links que se abrem também são descendentes desse `li` então a regra vale enquanto o mouse estiver em cima deles também.

Basta então fazeres `ul li:hover > a, ul li a:hover{` no 4o bloco de CSS do teu exemplo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Show Hide Dropdown Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        background: #f2f2f2;
    }
    ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 25px;
        color: #333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul li:hover > a, ul li a:hover{ /* <--------- mudei aqui */
        color: #fff;
        background: #939393;
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown{
        min-width: 125px; /* Set width of the dropdown */
        background: #f2f2f2;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 999;
        left: 0;
    }
    ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
        display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
    }
    ul li ul.dropdown li{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Products &#9662;</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Printers</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Como pedido nos comments](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74168/sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-menu-dropdown/74182?noredirect=1#comment151748_74182) aqui fica a mesma funcionalidade a titulo de exemplo só com JavaScript, mas o melhor é fazer só com CSS como no exemplo em cima e não com JavaScript.

**Exemplo JS:  [jsfiddle.net/tpmzLaro/](http://jsfiddle.net/tpmzLaro/)**

Comment: Sergio, como seria a mesma solução em Javascript puro? Você sabe?

Comment: É só a título de informação mesmo. Se pudesse fazer, ficaria grato.

Comment: @ErickLemos juntei exemplo no fim da resposta.